# egrep redirection not working when following tail of file

Tags: command-line, unix, redirection

I want to redirect the filtered output of a tail -f, as follows:

```
tail -f myfile | egrep '(searchterm_a)|(searchterm_b)' >> outputfile.txt
```

But for some reason the redirection is not working as I would have expected it to. Instead, an empty file is created.

Does anyone have an idea of where I have made an error?

Comment: Are you sure that your 2 part egrep search target works as you expect? What happens if you leave out the >> outFile. It might help to make a test file that has the values you are searching for execute that as egrep 'pat1|pat2' testFile, to be sure your patterns are working. My apologies if this is obvious for you, no offence intended ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a buffering issue (see e.g. [a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341297/write-to-a-file-after-piping-output-from-tail-f-through-to-grep/5341550)). You could try for example:

```
tail -f myfile | egrep --line-buffered '(searchterm_a)|(searchterm_b)' >> outputfile.txt
```